# XSLT/XPath - count adjacent nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to transform a table with row span from docx-xml to html. The problem is to count the number of cells that are spanned. I need the number of rows for the html-attribute "rowspan".

In docx-xml first cell with rowspan is indicated with `<span-element/attribute>`. The following spanned cells are indicated only by `<span-element>` - without an attribute. So I need to count the number of `<span-elements>`, immediate following the `<span-element> with attribute`.

I need to count cells in every column separately - since in every column can be another different rowspan.
I also can´t count just the total amount of `<span-element>` in a column - since there can be more than one rowspan.

I tried different approaches: I counted with `<xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::w:tc[1][//w:vmerge])"/>` - which is fine as long as there is only one occurance of rowspan. I tried to group adjacent nodes with for-each-group, but don´t know how to count nodes in it.

Simplified structure of original code:

```
<tbl>
    <tr>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <tc>
      <span-element/start-attribute>
       </tc>
        <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <tc>
       <span-element>
    </tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <tc>
      <span-element/start-attribute>
       </tc>
    <tc>
      <span-element/start-attribute>
       </tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <tc>
      <span-element>
        </tc>
    <tc>
      <span-element>
        </tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <tc>
      <span-element>
       </tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
    <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
</tbl>
```

My template:

```
<xsl:template match="tc">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="span-element[@start-attribute]">
                <td>
                    <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::tc[1][span-element])"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="span-element[not(@start-attribute)]"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

The second `<xsl:when>` deletes occurances of cells with "span-element" without "start-attribute" as needed in wanted HTML-result. There is also gridspan in the real document, which I need to also integrate later (this is why in the actual result provided below in the 4th and 7th row only is one cell less than expected).

Actual result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<table xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Zeile 1, Zelle 1</th>
      <th>Zeile 1, Zelle 2</th>
      <th>Zeile 1, Zelle 3</th>
      <th>Zeile 1, Zelle 4</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Zeile 2 + 3, Zelle 1</td>
      <td>Zeile 2, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 2, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 2, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 3, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 3, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 3, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 4, Zelle 1</td>
      <td>Zeile 4, Zelle 2 + 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 4, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Zeile 5 + 6 +7, Zelle 1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Zeile 5 + 6, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 5, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 5, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 6, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 6, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 7, Zelle 2 + 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 7, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 8, Zelle 1</td>
      <td>Zeile 8, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 8, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 8, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 9, Zelle 1</td>
      <td>Zeile 9, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 9, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 9, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Wanted result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<table xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Zeile 1, Zelle 1</th>
      <th>Zeile 1, Zelle 2</th>
      <th>Zeile 1, Zelle 3</th>
      <th>Zeile 1, Zelle 4</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Zeile 2 + 3, Zelle 1</td>
      <td>Zeile 2, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 2, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 2, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 3, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 3, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 3, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 4, Zelle 1</td>
      <td>Zeile 4, Zelle 2 + 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 4, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Zeile 5 + 6 +7, Zelle 1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Zeile 5 + 6, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 5, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 5, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 6, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 6, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 7, Zelle 2 + 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 7, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 8, Zelle 1</td>
      <td>Zeile 8, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 8, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 8, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Zeile 9, Zelle 1</td>
      <td>Zeile 9, Zelle 2</td>
      <td>Zeile 9, Zelle 3</td>
      <td>Zeile 9, Zelle 4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Which XSLT version can you use?

Comment: Up to version 2.0.

Comment: I guess this has been done already by others, for instance https://github.com/ottoville/DOCX2HTML.XSL/blob/master/table.xsl.

Comment: Thx, good hint, I´ll check this.

Comment: Works accurate.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT/XPath 1.0 context, traversing the following axis is better for grouping adjacents. The selection of nodes in the current group and nodes in the following groups is combined with set operations by means of the Kayian method.

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="span-element[@start-attribute]"/>
  <xsl:template match="tc[span-element[not(@start-attribute)]]"/>
  <xsl:template match="tc">
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="rowspan">
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="position()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="rowspan"/>
  <xsl:template match="tc[span-element/@start-attribute]" mode="rowspan">
      <xsl:param name="position"/>
      <xsl:variable 
        name="followings" 
        select="../following-sibling::tr/tc[$position]/span-element"/>
      <xsl:variable 
        name="mark" 
        select="$followings[@start-attribute][1]"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
          <xsl:value-of 
          select="count($followings[count(.|$mark|$mark/following::*)
                                    !=count($mark|$mark/following::*)]) + 1"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this **well-formed** input:

```
<tbl>
    <tr>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <tc>
         <span-element start-attribute=""/>
       </tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <tc>
         <span-element/>
        </tc>
        <tc>...</tc>
        <tc>...</tc>
        <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <tc>
        <span-element start-attribute=""/>
       </tc>
       <tc>
        <span-element start-attribute=""/>
       </tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
       <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <tc>
        <span-element/>
      </tc>
      <tc>
       <span-element/>
      </tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <tc>
        <span-element/>
      </tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
      <tc>...</tc>
     </tr>
</tbl>
```

Output:

```
<tbl>
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"/>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"/>
      <td rowspan="2"/>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
</tbl>
```

**Note**: this assumes that the input source has the correct fortmat (e.g. no overlapping).